# how can i access to UINavigationController with the string name

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c-runtime, kvc

my app has the navController

and at run time I have 
NSString *propertyName = @"navController";

and I know it is a type of UINavigationController

how can i access to UINavigationController with the string name

I might need to use https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) would help,

```
UINavigationController *navController = [self valueForKey:@"navController"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use runtime you can get the Ivar from whatever class navigationController is apart of by using this:

```
Ivar var =  class_getInstanceVariable(your class, "navController");
```

and then with that Ivar you call upon the instance of your class using this method to get the object navController points to

```
UINavigationController* controller = object_getIvar(instanceofyourclasswithnavcontroller, var)
```